# Convert JSON to DataTable without using NewtonSoft library

Tags: json, vb.net, datatable, .net-3.5

So i am working on deserializing a JSON string into a vb.net DataTable.
Now my project runs on .NET3.5 framework and hence i have to fall back on the stock JavaScriptSerializer to do the work. 
Is there a way to do this or does it need to done brute-force ?

Comment: Um, Json.NET works fine with .NET 3.5... why do you think you can't use it?

Comment: I never found a direct way to a DataTable - brute force using string processing Json routines with well known Json data was my approach.

Comment: @JonSkeet i was not aware that it supports .net 3.5 . Thanks for that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Json.Net

You **can** use Json.Net (it Supports .Net 3.5), something like this:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(json)
```

This will be the easiest to implement but of course your JSON needs to be in precisely the correct format for that to work, and that's not always easy (or possible), especially with complex types such as DataTables.

**Alternatively**

Depending on your JSON structure (an example would be useful) It might be easier to convert from JSON to a list of simple objects and then iterate over those objects to populate the the DataTable.

i.e. Create a new class matching your JSON schema:

```
Class SimpleObject

    Property Column1 As String
    ' etc.

End Class
```

Then loop through the list

```
    Dim ListFromJson As List(Of SimpleObject) =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of SimpleObject))(JsonString)

    For Each item As SimpleObject In ListFromJson
        ' Create new row from each item in the list and add to the table
    Next
```

In fact, with that approach, you might be able to do everything you need with the list itself, it will certainly be more efficient than a DataTable.

---

### Without using Json.NET

If you really don't want to use Json.NET (which is your easiest option, and the industry standard) then you can use `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json` [here is an example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/272335/JSON-Serialization-and-Deserialization-in-ASP-NET).

I am pretty sure that it wont automatically be able to convert to a DataTable though.

You will need to create a simple object as above to act as a middleman and loop through a list of those objects to put them in the DataTable.

Comment: Note the OP title "..without... NewtonSoft.." aka JSON.Net

Comment: @rheitzman you're quite right, added a reference to a `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json` for anyone that wants to be a martyr ;-)